# Google login with Firebase not working

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to integrate Google-signIn using Firebase, but the sign-in is not working.
It asks for selecting an account but does not gets signed in.

This is my code for MainActivity(The SignIn Activity) :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
        private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
        private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0 ;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
        private com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton signInButton;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private Button signOutButton;
        private TextView nameTextView;
        private TextView emailTextView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            signInButton = (com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
            signOutButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
            nameTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
            emailTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email_text_view);

            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.client_id))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this , new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                        }
                    } /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .build();

            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    signOutButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (user != null) {
                        // User is signed in
                        Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                        if(user.getDisplayName() != null)
                            nameTextView.setText("HI " + user.getDisplayName().toString());
                        emailTextView.setText(user.getEmail().toString());

                    } else {
                        // User is signed out
                        Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    }
                    // ...
                }
            };

            signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    signIn();
                }
            });
            signOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(Status status) {
                                    signInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    signOutButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    emailTextView.setText(" ".toString());
                                    nameTextView.setText(" ".toString());
                                }
                            });
                }
                // ..
            });

        }

        private void signIn() {
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                if (result.isSuccess()) {

                    GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                    firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

                } else {

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if (mAuthListener != null) {
                mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
            }
        }

        private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
            Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

            AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
            mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());


                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
}
```

This is my layout for MainActivity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="100dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello User"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Sign Out"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my logcat :

```
06-11 03:57:14.769 30651-30916/silive.in.friendlyshopping I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-11 03:57:14.769 30651-30916/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
06-11 03:57:14.809 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
06-11 03:57:14.819 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
06-11 03:57:14.819 30651-30916/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS is not allowed for Package : silive.in.friendlyshopping
06-11 03:57:14.909 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Connected to remote service
06-11 03:57:14.909 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@31a96d9 time:45321280
06-11 03:57:15.039 30651-30917/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/silive.in.friendlyshopping/shared_prefs/com.google.android.gms.appid.xml.bak
06-11 03:57:18.619 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:silive.in.friendlyshopping time:45324994
06-11 03:57:18.639 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=4018, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Splash, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8152285565647586081}]
06-11 03:57:18.679 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/ResourcesManager: Resource getTopLevelResources for package com.google.android.gmsoverlayDirs =Null
06-11 03:57:18.739 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000009/n/armeabi-v7a
06-11 03:57:18.739 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000009/n/armeabi
06-11 03:57:18.739 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/ResourcesManager: Resource getTopLevelResources for package com.google.android.gmsoverlayDirs =Null
06-11 03:57:18.799 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/AutoManageHelper: starting AutoManage for client 0 false null
06-11 03:57:18.809 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/AutoManageHelper: onStart true {0=com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcg$zza@f2773d3}
06-11 03:57:18.819 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
06-11 03:57:18.819 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b6b7a2f I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
06-11 03:57:18.819 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=Splash, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-8152285565647586081, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8152285565647586080}]
06-11 03:57:18.829 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/SignInActivity: onAuthStateChanged:signed_out
06-11 03:57:18.829 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/ActivityThread: AppLock checkAppLockState isAppLocked = false pkgName = silive.in.friendlyshopping showWhenLocked = false
06-11 03:57:18.849 30651-30916/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
06-11 03:57:18.889 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
06-11 03:57:18.909 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4ff000e time:45325288
06-11 03:57:19.149 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
06-11 03:57:24.809 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Logging event (FE): session_start(_s), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8152285565647586080}]
06-11 03:57:24.829 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Connected to remote service
06-11 03:57:32.459 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
06-11 03:57:32.929 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
06-11 03:57:34.869 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
06-11 03:57:34.969 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
06-11 03:57:34.969 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
06-11 03:57:34.969 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
06-11 03:57:34.979 30651-30850/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/silive.in.friendlyshopping/shared_prefs/com.google.firebase.auth.api.Store.W0RFRkFVTFRd+MTo5OTY5MjQ1MzQ2NzQ6YW5kcm9pZDo1ZDU2ZTIwMzk4ZGUwZGZk.xml.bak
06-11 03:57:34.989 30651-30850/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/silive.in.friendlyshopping/shared_prefs/com.google.android.gms.signin.xml.bak
06-11 03:57:34.989 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
06-11 03:57:34.989 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
06-11 03:57:34.989 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/SignInActivity: onAuthStateChanged:signed_out
06-11 03:57:39.409 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
06-11 03:57:39.539 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
06-11 03:57:39.539 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:silive.in.friendlyshopping time:45345918
06-11 03:57:39.579 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=20753, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8152285565647586080}]
06-11 03:57:39.609 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-8152285565647586080, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignInHubActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8152285565647586079}]
06-11 03:57:39.619 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
06-11 03:57:39.619 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{242bce9 I.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
06-11 03:57:39.639 30651-30916/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
06-11 03:57:39.659 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/ActivityThread: AppLock checkAppLockState isAppLocked = false pkgName = silive.in.friendlyshopping showWhenLocked = false
06-11 03:57:39.659 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Connected to remote service
06-11 03:57:39.669 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
06-11 03:57:39.669 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@25a6904 time:45346048
06-11 03:57:43.549 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SignInHubActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-8152285565647586079, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8152285565647586080}]
06-11 03:57:43.579 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
06-11 03:57:43.599 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/ActivityThread: AppLock checkAppLockState isAppLocked = false pkgName = silive.in.friendlyshopping showWhenLocked = false
06-11 03:57:43.599 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4ff000e time:45349974
06-11 03:58:09.649 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
06-11 03:58:09.899 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
06-11 03:58:13.839 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
06-11 03:58:13.969 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
06-11 03:58:13.969 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:silive.in.friendlyshopping time:45380343
06-11 03:58:13.989 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=30437, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8152285565647586080}]
06-11 03:58:14.009 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-8152285565647586080, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignInHubActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8152285565647586078}]
06-11 03:58:14.009 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
06-11 03:58:14.019 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{f639ccc I.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
06-11 03:58:14.029 30651-30916/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
06-11 03:58:14.029 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Connected to remote service
06-11 03:58:14.049 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/ActivityThread: AppLock checkAppLockState isAppLocked = false pkgName = silive.in.friendlyshopping showWhenLocked = false
06-11 03:58:14.059 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
06-11 03:58:14.069 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@7f43e1e time:45380440
06-11 03:58:16.419 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
06-11 03:58:16.439 30651-30864/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SignInHubActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-8152285565647586078, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8152285565647586080}]
06-11 03:58:16.439 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4ff000e time:45382817
06-11 03:58:16.439 30651-30651/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/ActivityThread: AppLock checkAppLockState isAppLocked = false pkgName = silive.in.friendlyshopping showWhenLocked = false
06-11 03:58:57.009 30651-32456/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=40582, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8152285565647586080}]
06-11 03:58:57.059 30651-32456/silive.in.friendlyshopping D/FA: Connected to remote service
06-11 04:02:14.709 30651-30843/silive.in.friendlyshopping W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

I am using this link for reference : https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/firebase/android-firebase-authentication-tutorial-using-firebase-google-login/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use this url instead https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: Thanks for the reference but I have already tried this link, the problem persists.

Comment: I don't think it is from your fcm code. Start a new android project. The fault is from you activity. And why is there a list view.

Comment: Well, I tried that too, I am stuck the same problem and there is no ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this change and check if its getting logged.

```
 if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {

                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

            } else {
                Log.i("ErrorSignIn", result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you enabled the Google Login provider in the Firebase console?

Comment: result.getStatus().getStatusMessage()); returns null.

Comment: @Matt, Yeah I have.